# Azure Digital Twin - RBAC access for models/twins

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

With new version of Azure Digital Twin, how to enable RBAC access apart from owner/reader role to the digital twin. Similar to previous version, where we would be able to provide access at any level to particular user/tenant id, will it be possible to provide role access at a particular node and below.

I assume in below command, it supports only owner/reader role.

```
az dt rbac assign-role -n <adtinstance> --role owner -g <resourcegroup> --assignee <serviceprincipal>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of Azure Digital Twins has no built-in support to assign roles to subsets of the graph. Like in your example, you can create an owner or reader for the entire graph.

Comment: If you believe this should be a feature to be added in the new version of ADT add a new entry in [Azure Digital Twins feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/916621-azure-digital-twins) with proper business justification so others can vote and comment as well.